# How to connect these together?

Tags: c++, mysql, phpmyadmin, qt-creator

I've got a mysql database created by phpMyAdmin and I want to use it in my Qt project. I tried it on Visual Studio 2010 with an qt addon but it didn't work.

In Qt Creator, I add:

```
QT += sql
```

in a .pro file and include:

```
#include <QSqlDatabase>
```

in the main file but there's a driver error.

I don't know even where to start and each google page shows something different. I tried to look for some guide but there is nothing which concerns everything in []s.

**EDIT:**

Error: QMYSQL driver not loaded

I know I should look here: http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/sql-driver.html but I don't know what I am looking for.

I tried this: http://www.seppemagiels.com/blog/create-mysql-driver-qt-windows but I don't have mingw thing.

Comment: "didn't work neither" means it worked, so what's the problem?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: What driver error do you receive?

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Qt Visual Studio Add-In](https://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-other) and in Qt project options mark SQL (not sure about the correct name, but I can tell you later). That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You must compile drivers separately from Qt. In this case, you need the MySql driver.
Look here:
http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/sql-driver.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't get it. I've installed mysql-5.5.28-win32.msi and I want to follow "How to Build the QMYSQL Plugin on Windows" but there is no ' "Custom Install". 

Install the "Libs & Include Files" ' option.
I don't know what exactly concerns my problem.